# Administrate a SQL Server 2000 database from Windows and Change a whole column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

i have some experience with MySQL but none with SQL Server, i have a computer who host a database (SQL Server 2000) and i have local access to it. The think is that one column of the table **NomAntiguedad** need to be change from a given date period; I need to multiply by 0.01 all the values of the column between the values of **mesano** (05/2007 to actual date, format: MM/YYYY).

How can i have **VISUAL** access to the data base, like when i administrate my data bases on PhpMyAdmin in order to see the tables format?

What would be the syntax of the command to do what i need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i have VISUAL access to the data base, like when i administrate my data bases on PhpMyAdmin in order to see the tables format?

There's the defacto [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) (Express Edition is free), or [Toad for SQL Server](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm) (free if <5 people use it in-house) applications...

> The think is that one column of the table NomAntiguedad  need to be change from a given date period; I need to multipli for 0.01 all the values of the column between the values of mesano  (05/2007 to actual date, format: MM/YYYY).

You need to use an [UPDATE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

```
UPDATE NomAntiguedad
   SET your_column = .01 * your_column
 WHERE mesano = '05/2007'
```

Mind that you might have to use [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to explicitly handle the data type returned from the ".01 * your_column" calculation because you could be loosing precision depending on the column's data type.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE NomAntiguedad
SET <Column You're Updating> = .01*<Column You're Updating>
WHERE REPLACE(mesano, '/', '/01/') BETWEEN '5/1/2007' AND getDate()
```

I'm assuming you're date format is accurate and never changes.

Comment: "BETWEEN '5/1/2007' AND getDate()" that is not the date format the database use. Is MM/YYYY. Knowing that how can i change the syntax of your command? Thanks

Comment: Is mesano stored as a DateTime column in your database?  If so SQL server should just know how to handle it.

Comment: MM/YYYY isn't a standard date format; to support the slash, it'd have to be text based (VARCHAR, etc.)

Comment: Ok I stand corrected :-)  See my update above.   It feels a bit hack-ish, but I always prefer treating Dates as Dates instead of varchar strings.